# Deadlock while trying to sync a thread-unsafe call from two threads into another thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

In my current project, we are using a 3rd party library which is designed to run only from a single thread. But our project is multi-threaded. I don't know if it is very common but I did the simplest thing to solve the race conditions.

I come up with a design in which our threads have to ask a specific single thread for this thread-unsafe call. For example we already had thread A and B, and now I come up with a thread C.
And if A or B want the calculation (to be done with the 3rd party library), they have to ask from C. C will reply only one thread at each time and that is fine even A and B will be blocked if one of them already is asked and waiting for C to complete.

I wanted to implement that with conditional variables but I am still having deadlocks. Can you please see [my example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b6796f342b05c709) which I removed my extra data structures and tell me if I should change my approach or if you see a part which might cause deadlocks can you please give your suggestions about that parts of the code.

Comment: If thread `C` is blocked, the calling thread (either `A` or `B`) will be blocked too. So, why not controlling the entrance to the whole external library with a mutex and do not use `C` at all?

Comment: When I had to solve the same problem, I wrote a function that client threads could call to post a request to a blocking queue, and I had it immediately return a future-like object to the caller. The worker thread (i.e., the owner of the thread-unsafe library) would pick a request object from the queue, perform the work, and then "complete" the associated future-like object before going back to the top of the loop to pick the next request from the queue.